# Math calculation laravel (netto-brutto)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<h4><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i> Rechnung preis - Brutto €</h4>
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
<h5><strong>{{ $data->bedrag_rechnung_brutto }}</h5></strong>
</div>
</div>
```

But I have also another field Rechnung preis - Netto. What must be the code for calculate netto-brutto from bedrag_rechnung_brutto. It must be -19%.

Netto = brutto /1,19.

Comment: No. It must be netto = brutto /1,19.

brutto = € 119,00
netto = € 119,00 /1,19 = €100,00.
It is right.

Comment: `netto = brutto / 1,19`

Comment: `brutto = netto * 1,19`

Comment: or

I have a field bedrag_rechnung_netto in my database. I can also send directly to the field database bedrag_rechnung_netto but wthat will be code to send (bedrag_rechnung_brutto / 1,19).

Comment: `netto = €100,00;
VAT = €100,00 * 19%;
brutto = netto * 1,19;
brutto = €100,00 * 1,19 = €119;

netto = brutto / 1,19;
netto = €119 / 1,19 = €100;
`

Comment: So what is your actual question here then? How to perform basic Math operations in PHP, or what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your question over here? You already answered it yourself?

```
$netto = $brutto/1.19;
```

Comment: i can't comment other threads because isufficent right. The math is perfectly right. 
Your assumption is wrong. The problem is that the tax base is always the netto amount. So if you have a brutto price of 200€ the tax (19%) is added to the price of 168,07€ - not to 162€. If you add  19% to 168,07€ you get the 200€ back. if you add 19% to your 162€ (*0,81) you will only get 192,78€

Comment: to clarify: https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/net-to-gross?c=EUR&v=gross:200,tax_from_net:19!perc

net price is the base for calculating - not gross

Answer (score 0):

code:
`$netto = $brutto/1.19;`
is right and it works.
I close it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with:

```
$netto = $brutto/1.19;
```

For exaple if brutto price is 8€ and has tax rate is 23% You will get:

```
$netto = 8/1.23 // 6.5040..
```

in accountings you have 2 decimals precision so your netto is 6.50€
but if You calculate brutto from 6.50 (6.50 * 1.23) You will get brutto 7.995
evene when you rount it to 2 digits You will receive 7.99€

I solve this problem with simple function that subtracts a few euro cents and after that loops increasing netto to find real one:

```
public function getNettoPrice($brutto, $taxRate) {
    $netto = $brutto / $taxRate;
    $netto -= 0.02;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i += 0.01) {
        $testValue = number_format($netto + $i, 2) * $taxRate;
        $testValuePrecision = substr(number_format($testValue, 3), 0, -1);
        if (number_format($price, 2) === $testValuePrecision) {
            return $netto + $i;
        }
    }
    return $netto;
}
```